# MongoDB only one item, post or put?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

POST to create a new item, PUT to update an item.. but what if there's only one item in the database?

Do I code: 'if item already exists, find it and PUT' else 'POST'

or am I missing something very obvious?

I briefly thought of doing post everytime, and on the first line of the post just delete everything, then post, but that seems dumb

Comment: Related: [In REST is POST or PUT best suited for upsert operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470588/in-rest-is-post-or-put-best-suited-for-upsert-operation)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer to `POST` for the original creation, and `PATCH` for updates...

---

#### If you have the id, or can generate it on the client (such as a uuid):

`PUT /myresources/:id`

#### If you don't have the id, or need to generate it on the server:

`POST /myresources`

should return a `location` header with the generated path, as well as an acceptable response body.

```
{
  id: "someid",
  location: "/myresources/someid"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question (at least as far as my read of it goes).  The question Jonathan linked to is identical.