# Should I POST to the collection when creating a resource with a known ID in my REST API?

Tags: rest, api, post

I'm implementing a new REST API. In this API I typically POST to collections to create resources. For one of my resources, the ID is known before it is created. Does it make more sense to post to the collection with the ID in the body or to post to the instance (as yet non-existent) with the ID in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say keep the existing endpoint and just add the `ID` in the body when `POST`ing to that collection, there's no point in adding a new separate route for what's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

From another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18474955/1851581

You can also use `PUT` with the `ID` in the URL, instead of POST.

`PUT` is used for upserting, covering mainly updates but also the creation of the resource if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting to the collection with the ID in the body. That keeps with the pattern elsewhere in my API. The only difference here is that the ID is supplied in the body.